# Failed to pull public image from dockerhub in Kubernetes

Tags: docker, kubernetes, dockerhub

I have created a yaml file which tries to pull a public image from dockerhub. More specifically, I am trying to pull minio client from here: https://hub.docker.com/r/minio/mc/.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: minio-admin-create-bucket
  namespace: minio
  labels:
    app: minio
spec:
  completions: 1
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: minio-admin
        image: minio/mc
        env:
        - name: MINIO_ACCESS_POINT
          value: $minio_endpoint
        - name: MINIO_ACCESS_KEY
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: minio-keys
              key: access-key
        - name: MINIO_SECRET_KEY
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: minio-keys
              key: secret-key
        command: ["/bin/sh", "-c"]
        args: ["mc alias set minio \$MINIO_ACCESS_POINT \$MINIO_ACCESS_KEY \$MINIO_SECRET_KEY --api S3v4; mc mb minio/$bucketName;"]
      restartPolicy: Never
  backoffLimit: 2
```

In the `args` I utilize two commands:

```
mc alias set minio \$MINIO_ACCESS_POINT \$MINIO_ACCESS_KEY \$MINIO_SECRET_KEY --api S3v4;
```

which adds a Cloud Storage Service and

```
mc mb minio/$bucketName;"
```

which creates a bucket.

Of course, I have created and pass all the variables ($minio_endpoint, $MINIO_ACCESS_POINT, etc.)

However, when I run `kubectl get pods -n minio` I get

> minio-admin-create-bucket-x94sk   0/1     ImagePullBackOff   0

For more details I run  `kubectl describe pods minio-admin-create-bucket-x94sk -n minio` and the output is:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                From               Message
  ----     ------     ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  7m7s               default-scheduler  Successfully assigned minio/minio-admin-create-bucket-x94sk to antonis-dell
  Warning  Failed     3m14s              kubelet            Failed to pull image "minio/mc": rpc error: code = FailedPrecondition desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/minio/mc:latest": failed commit on ref "layer-sha256:8643f6c7725de03080fbbd84f488839af54ac05cc0b410c91fb0c3b0c0705105": unexpected commit digest sha256:20314caaf7f65ec3ab88e7a12c3494132fb35d0859f4bbc1dc80b6030f63cf09, expected sha256:8643f6c7725de03080fbbd84f488839af54ac05cc0b410c91fb0c3b0c0705105: failed precondition
  Warning  Failed     3m14s              kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
  Normal   BackOff    3m13s              kubelet            Back-off pulling image "minio/mc"
  Warning  Failed     3m13s              kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling    3m (x2 over 7m6s)  kubelet            Pulling image "minio/mc"
```

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

I removed the folder `/var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.content.v1.content/ingest/` as @Nick ODell sugested and now the error is:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age               From               Message
  ----     ------     ----              ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled  24s               default-scheduler  Successfully assigned minio/minio-admin-create-bucket-4qtkw to knodea
  Normal   BackOff    19s               kubelet            Back-off pulling image "minio/mc"
  Warning  Failed     19s               kubelet            Error: ImagePullBackOff
  Normal   Pulling    7s (x2 over 23s)  kubelet            Pulling image "minio/mc"
  Warning  Failed     3s (x2 over 19s)  kubelet            Failed to pull image "minio/mc": rpc error: code = NotFound desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/minio/mc:latest": no match for platform in manifest: not found
  Warning  Failed     3s (x2 over 19s)  kubelet            Error: ErrImagePull
```

Comment: Does this solve your problem? https://github.com/containerd/containerd/issues/3974#issuecomment-593086459

Comment: When I executed sudo rm -rf /var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.content.v1.content/ingest/ seems to solve the problem but now my error is Failed to pull image "minio/mc": rpc error: code = NotFound desc = failed to pull and unpack image "docker.io/minio/mc:latest": no match for platform in manifest: not found

Comment: Can you remake that directory with `mkdir`? It probably expects the directory to be there.

Comment: Unfortunately no

Comment: Have you restarted `docker.service` after those manipulations with folder? Also can you just pull this image manually via docker? Or another one to make sure it works in general and something is with this exact one? Based on [their documentation](https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-quickstart-guide) they suggest using [minio-operator](https://github.com/minio/operator/blob/master/README.md) for kubernetes.